# 2 Regular Expressions to extract build no and version name

Tags: regex, pcre

Im really struggling to understand regular expressions.

I have this string:

```
Windows SERVERMAIN 10.0.14393 Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard x64
```

I need to create two regular expressions.

The first one should return the part of the string after the second space and before the third space, so I am left with:

```
10.0.14393
```

The second one should return everything after the third space, so I am left with:

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard x64
```

Is anyone able to help me with this, so far I have only been able to use:

```
\s+\w+\s(.*)
```

Which gives me:

```
SERVERMAIN 10.0.14393 Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard x64
```

**Update 1**
After the help from @rock321987, I've reviewed how I want to implement this.

I now have this string:

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter x64 - 10.0.14393
```

Which I want to split into two groups:

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter x64

10.0.14393
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regex 1](https://regex101.com/r/0EuZHA/1/)

```
^.*?[ ]+.*?[ ]+(.*?)[ ]
```

[Regex 2](https://regex101.com/r/0EuZHA/2/)

```
^.*?[ ]+.*?[ ]+.*?[ ]+(.*)$
```

*Regex 1 Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of string
.*?[ ]+ #Match till 1st space
.*?[ ]+ #Match till 2nd space
(.*?)[ ]+ #Capture the match after 2nd space till 3rd space
```

*Regex 2 Breakdown*

```
^.*?[ ]+.*?[ ]+.*?[ ]+ #Explanation same as above. Match till 3rd space
(.*)$ #Match everything after 3rd space till last
```

**EDIT**: This can be done in single regex too if your tool allows

```
^.*?[ ]+.*?[ ]+(.*?)[ ]+(.*)$
```

**EDIT 1**: If you want you can use `\K` too like

```
^.*?[ ]+.*?[ ]+\K([^ ]+)
```

Comment: When trying Regex 1 on https://regex101.com/r/KaFdfn/1, it shows a Full Match and Group 1, I need it just as Full Match, if that makes sense?

Comment: you need to extract `group 1` from your language

Comment: Im not sure how to do this? At the moment for output im putting '\0'

Comment: use `\1` for first capturing group

Comment: Just after I wrote my comment I thought it might be that simple and tried it. Many thanks!

Comment: cool.. try single regex in first edit I mentioned.. `\1` for first group, `\2` for second group

Comment: I have put an update in my post, because you've made me understand groups, and how I can manipulate the data, what I want to do has now changed, do you mind looking at Update 1?

Comment: Almost there...managed to get Full and Group 1, with: ^.*?[-][ ]+(.*)$

Comment: I think I've done it, does this look right to you: ^(.*)[ ][-][ ]+(.*)$

Comment: @Jeffrey yep.. seems correct.. but this heavily depends on your input.. if some part of this string `Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter x64` contains `-`, it will be inccorrect

Comment: It should not do, but I will know shortly if it causes any problems.